# how to push indepedent repos to individual branches in remote in git?

Tags: git

I am very new to git so please bear with my basic questions.

Recently I accidentally did a `rm –rf *` in a directory :(

I was looking at git. I have set up a local repo and started working with git.

Now I have turned more ambitious. I was thinking if I can share code amongst my trees using a local remote. The trees are exactly identical and numbered
*tree1*, *tree2* etc.

I have 4 trees. All of them have respective git tracking for the changes I am doing in them. I was thinking if I can get changes from one tree into another when I need using git.

I might not need all the changes also … but only limited changes in the form of certain files and folders.

What do the git masters here suggest? Options are:

- shall I just copy over the files when needed and keep life simple?
- use git patch?
- create a local remote which has the tree names as branch? and use cherry pick to move across the changes

If it is the 3rd option can someone help me with the commands as to how to set up the remote?

I know this is not an ideal situation, unless I finally refactor my codebase is there a way to do something like ?

- main repo has *n* branches pertaining to each of the tree
- each tree pushes to each of the branch

Is this possible? I could not find the commands to do this kind of structure.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly opinionated, any of those options would work.  It's a matter of preference. Since you want to learn more about git, I'd go for the third solution.

First you'll have to create the local repo:

```
git init --bare $PATH_TO_NEW_REPO_LOCATION
```

Create the respective branches by successively going into all *tree* repos and type

```
git remote add local-remote $PATH_TO_NEW_REPO_LOCATION
git push local-remote -u master:$TREE_BRANCH
```

where `$TREE_BRANCH` is the branch name which must be different for each *tree*.  This will create the branch in the new repo and sets the new branch as upstream to your current branch.  So the next time you do <kbd>git push</kbd>, it will push to the correct branch.

If you have some changes you want to cherry pick and pushed the changed tree to the remote, update the local repo with <kbd>git fetch --all</kbd> and then pick the right commit using <kbd>git log local-remote/$TREE_BRANCH</kbd> and <kbd>git cherry-pick $COMMIT_HASH</kbd>.

Comment: will `git push local-remote -u master:$TREE_BRANCH` push all the branches of the _tree_ repo?

Comment: No, just the master.  Repeat the command with *master* replaced with every branch you want to push